# Textmate Execute line/selection for Python broken

Tags: python, textmate

I've been using textmate for python for a couple of weeks now, everything seems to be working fine apart from the command "Execute line/selection as Python". It does not work at all. Trying to test even

```
print "Hello World"
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/temp_textmate.QrxfR3", line 19, in <module>
  stdout.write(exc)
  TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not list
```

I tried to re-install textmate but still getting the same error. Any idea?????

my version of textmate is Version 1.5.10 (1623)

thanks,

Alberto

Comment: Please format your code correctly.  Please copy and paste the **actual** code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going on here. The first is that the command "Execute line/selection as Python" is broken. The exception you're seeing is a consequence of a bug in the implementation of "Execute line/selection as Python" when trying to retrieve the call stack. Why this is happening is something of a poser, which I'm currently looking into. The second issue is that the implementation of "Execute line/selection as Python" calls `eval` which expects an expression to be executed, not a statement, which causes the exception to be raised.

This answer assumes that you are using Python 2.x.